# How to manage emails from a mailing list in gmail

Tags: email, gmail

I have created a label in Gmail so that all emails coming from a particular address get tagged with the label. However, I would like for these emails to not appear in my inbox at all. This is a mailing list and so not all emails are important or relevant. Most of the time they are simply littering my inbox.

How can I redirect these emails such that they get stored in a separate folder and don't appear as unread messages in my inbox?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail filters can handle this for you.  Create a filter (or edit your existing filter) and make sure to select the first option "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)" in addition to applying the label to the filtered emails.  This way the emails will go to 'All Mail' in Gmail as well as inside the label/folder you created.

You could also apply "Mark as read" if that suits your needs.